# Building regular expression

Tags: regex, parsing

I am making regex for my code parser. I need to recognize string literal, and i made this regex:

```
"([^"]|(\\"))+"?
```

I need to match these cases:

```
"Some String
"another string \" string
"blah blah \" blah "
```

and these not:

```
"Some String"a
"blah blah \" blah "b
```

It have to start with **"**

after that there should be any character except **"**

If there is another **"** it must be at the end, or it must be escaped with **\**

My regex doest work :( I tested at: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ If i have this case:

```
"asdasdsd\"sadasd
```

it select only:

```
"asdasdsd\"
```

why?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: I was looking for: ^"([^"]|(\\"))+([^\\]")?$
Now, its perfectly work!

Comment: What should happen if the backslash is escaped as well? Like this  `"asdasdsd\\"sadasd`? Now the first part `"asdasdsd\\"` is a completely enclosed string.

Comment: I hope this will never happen :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse the or operation ... here it is in python

```
>>> print re.search(r'"(\\"|[^"])+','"asdasdsd\\"sadasd').group(0)
"asdasdsd\"sadasd
```

The reason being that, having [^"] first, sucks up your backslash, then fails out when it hits the quote

this

```
"([^"]|(\\"))+"?
```

becomes

```
"(\\"|[^"])+"?
```

*note: I don't know if you need the '?' since you didn't specify a language.  The above python implementation should hopefully get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Regex?

It seems that your case would be simpler and clearer if you just used standard string parsing toools in the language of your choice.

Comment: Yes, i am tokenizing code with regular expresion based of regular languges. Its part of my bachelor work :(